# Difference between Karma start and grunt karma:unit

Tags: unit-testing, gruntjs, karma-runner

Can anybody explain to me what is the difference between the `karma start` and `grunt karma:unit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
karma start my.conf.js
```

You will launch your tests directly on your CLI with a config file given as parameters

@see: http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/intro/configuration.html

> When starting Karma, the configuration file path can be passed as the first argument.
>   By default, Karma would look for karma.conf.js or karma.conf.coffee in the > current directory.
>
> Start Karma using your configuration:
>
> $ karma start my.conf.js

With

```
grunt karma:unit
```

One uses the task "**karma**" with the target "**unit**" defined into your GruntFile.

In other words when one uses **grunt karma:unit** grunt does a **karma start** in background

Comment: according to your answer, their is no difference b/w both commands please correct me if i m wrong.

Comment: There is a difference! The first one you use a tool (karma) and with the other, you start a tool (karma) WITH an other tool (grunt) :)
In other words, grunt is not able to do unit test alone but it's able to start karma

Comment: Yes, at the end you will have the same result :) (if your GruntFile is well created)